# Ionic 2 Native Google Maps Error

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

Kindly check the image below:
[image]

I just followed the instructions from the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/

The error happens on creating the map. It seems that GoogleMaps object doesn't have getPlugin method which results to property BaseArrayClass cannot be read.

**Actual Codes**

home.ts

```
import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 GoogleMapOptions,
 CameraPosition,
 MarkerOptions,
 Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
    map: GoogleMap;
  mapElement: HTMLElement;

  constructor(
    private googleMaps: GoogleMaps,
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams
    ) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');
    console.log(this.googleMaps);
    this.loadMap();
  }

    loadMap() {
      this.mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

      let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
        camera: {
          target: {
            lat: 43.0741904,
            lng: -89.3809802
          },
          zoom: 18,
          tilt: 30
        }
      };

      this.map = this.googleMaps.create(this.mapElement, mapOptions);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please dont add code as an image.. [edit] the question with text of both code and error

Comment: @suraj the image is not the actual code i've done it is from the developer console.

Comment: can you try calling the plugin within `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`?

Comment: @suraj i'll try thanks

Comment: @suraj error still occurs